# What is the opposite of explode function?

Tags: php, arrays

This is how I explode a sentence into an array of words:

`$words = explode(" ", $sentence)`;

How do you do the opposite? (take an array such as `$words` with single numeric keys into a variable storing a string such as `$sentence` with spaces between words)

Comment: why was this downvoted so much?

Comment: because If you visited the explode documentation you would have read that implode was what you were looking for. I'm sure they would prefer to downvote the question asker if they could. Saying that I wouldn't downvote, its a simple/easy well formed question which just requires a simple answer. nothing wrong their. This question will help a lot of noobs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$sentence = implode(' ',$words);
```

Answer (score 4):

[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

use implode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$sentence = implode(' ', $words);
```

[implode](http://www.php.net/implode)

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Hello World";
$explode = explode(" ",$string);
print_r($explode); //explode[0] = Hello, explode[1] = World

$explode = array([0]=>Hello,[1]=>World);
$string = implode(" ",$string);
echo $string; // Hello World
```

Comment: You have a mistake in your code. Shouldn't it be ```$string = implode(" ", $explode);```